# Uipath Orchestrator: Error while running a process in orchestrator

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I have a process that takes a screenshot and save it in the absolute path and send the image in the email as HTML code.

While running the process locally the screenshots are correct with the right date and time. 
However, when I publish the process in the orchestrator when the process is running the connection gets disconnected and the screenshot that is sent in the email is the same screenshot taken before publishing the process.

Please advice what could be the issue

I Have added the path where the screenshot to be saved
and called the same path in the HTML code that includes the image tag.

HTML code :
For the screenshot in Uipath I have used:
1. take screenshot activity
2.save image: path is E\Auto-dashboard\test.png

in the email that includes the screenshot in the body, should include the latest screenshot of the dashboard with the correct date and time

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your workflow? I replicated your scenario and i get the correct result for both running the process from the robot or Orchestrator. Are you using any input and output parameters for your process in Orchestrator?

Comment: As @KonstantinosPalaiodimos says, please post your workflow so the community can help you. It may be anything from selector to paths, or the most simple error

Comment: So based on what I understood from your question, it seems to me that the orchestrator is not successful in running your process and is simply sending the one previously sent probably by default. Nothing can be said for sure unless you post the workflow. Kindly do it.